# Erro ao consumir API em flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, post, request

Erro:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI localhost:3000/usuario/cadastro
#0      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2694:9)
#1      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2591:7)
#2      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:57:38)
#3      BaseRequest.send (package:http/src/base_request.dart:133:35)
#4      _MyHomePageState.main (package:teste/main.dart:42:52)
#5      _MyHomePageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:teste/main.dart:151:21)
#6      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
#9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
#10     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)
#11     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615:9)
#12     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
#13     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
#14     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
#15     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
#16     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
#17     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:460:19)
#18     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
#19     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
#20     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
#21     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
#22     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
#23     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
#24     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
#25     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
#26     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
```

Função/Método:

```
  void main(String nome, String usuario, String email, String celular,
      String senha) async {
    var request =
        http.Request('POST', Uri.parse('localhost:3000/usuario/cadastro'));
    request.body =
        '''{\r\n    "email": "emailusuario@email.com",\r\n    "senha": "senhaUsuario",\r\n    "nome": "Nome Usuario",\r\n    "usuario": "usuario123",\r\n    "celular": "(11)99876-1563"\r\n}''';

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
  }
```

Controllers:

```
  TextEditingController nome = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController usuario = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController celular = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController senha = TextEditingController();
```

TextFormField:

```
Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: nome,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Nome',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: usuario,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Usuário',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: email,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'E-mail',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: celular,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Celular',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: senha,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Senha',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: senha,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Repita a Senha',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

Botão:

```
            SizedBox(
              height: 50.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 25.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    main(nome.text, usuario.text, email.text, celular.text,
                        senha.text);
                  },
                  child: Text('CADASTRAR'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/usuario/cadastro`

Comment: Para viabilizar sua postagem vide instruções dadas a 1a vez que perguntou https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/569947/